# Laravel Query with if/else operators

Tags: laravel

Is there a use like the example below?

```
//Let's say there is $data from the user. Can I shape the query based on this value?

if($data==1{
  $q->whereDate('start_date', '<=', '2021-01-01');
  
}else if($data==0){
  $q->whereDate('end_date', '<=', '2021-02-02');
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your question more? I am not quite sure what about that you are asking about.

Comment: @lagbox Thank you for your answer. I rearranged the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$q->when(1==1, function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('start_date', '<=', '2021-01-01');
}, function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('end_date', '<=', '2021-02-02');
});
```

The first closure is called if the truth check passes, the second closure is executed if the truth check fails.

You obviously need to substitute `1==1` for an actual equality check you want to run as `1==1` will always be true...

Comment: Thank u for answer!